# Div disappears when height is a percentage or auto

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem. I've created some tiles with CSS, as can be seen in the example below, and it all works well when I set the tile's div height and width in pixels.

However, when I set the div height as a percentage (or to auto, as I would like), the div disappears. I can set the width to a percentage without a problem.

**The problem can be seen in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vtmwJ).**

P.S. I would like to solve this problem without any Javascript or JQuery :-)

Many thanks!

Comment: All elements inside your div are absolute positioned, it's like they don't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the elements inside of your tile divs are positioned absolutely which removes them from the flow of your document and makes the tile div height 0 (see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)).

Remove `position: absolute;` from one of your containing elements (in your case probably the caption) and have it `display: block;`.

Here a working [fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DFxCg).

Comment: Didn't know this, many thanks! You really helped me out :-) Just one final question: somehow, the height of the div is scaled according to the text, not the image. Could I change this?

Comment: Yes... you could leave the text positioned absolutely and instead change the image to be static. Just make sure the elements are in the right position, here an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GAcve